# Get just the time from System.DateTime

Tags: c#

Hi I have a local variable of the type of System.DateTime. How can I get just the time? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is for display purposes (As it normally is with these questions), you can simply use one of the following:

```
myDateTime.ToShortTimeString();

myDateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); //for 12 hour clock

myDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); //for 24 hour clock
```

Answer (score 6):

[`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) returns a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) representing the time of the day.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string time_now =dt.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```